# FT2232H - FT245 Synchronous FIFO mode read timing

Tags: timing

I'm trying to understand the read timing diagram of the [FT2232H](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT2232H.pdf) in FT245 Synchronous FIFO mode so that I can properly configure the state machine of the FPGA attached to it. Here's the datasheet page for the timing diagram (read timing upper half)

[image]

And the corresponding description.

[image]

This seems to indicate that the positive edge of CLKOUT sampling OE# low and RD# high reads the first data word from the RX buffer (assuming RXF# is low). In contrast, all subsequent data words are made available by sampling both OE# low and RD# low (also assuming RXF# is low).

Is this correct? Or, is the first word available after RD# is sampled low? Or, something else?

I feel fairly confident that the first option is right, but the read state machine does not work as expected so I'd like to be sure I didn't miss something here.

Can OE# be kept low if RXF# temporarily goes high, and then reads after RXF# returns low would follow RD# being sampled low?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while (2007) since I worked with the FT245 — I had an FPGA (coded in VHDL) passing bidirectional data to/from a host PC using it.

Note that RXF# is a bit of a misnomer. It doesn't mean that the Rx FIFO is full, only that it is not empty. Similarly, TXE# doesn't mean that the Tx FIFO is empty, only that it is not full. I'm not sure why they picked those signal names — I found it rather confusing at first.

> This seems to indicate that the positive edge of CLKOUT sampling OE#
> low and RD# high reads the first data word from the RX buffer
> (assuming RXF# is low). In contrast, all subsequent data words are
> made available by sampling both OE# low and RD# low (also assuming
> RXF# is low).
>
> Is this correct? Or, is the first word available after RD# is sampled
> low? Or, something else?

The first word is *available* as soon as you drive OE# low. But it doesn't change until the chip sees RD# low on a rising clock edge. In other words, you should capture the data whenever RXF# and RD# are both low on a rising clock edge.

> Can OE# be kept low if RXF# temporarily goes high, and then reads
> after RXF# returns low would follow RD# being sampled low?

Yes, you can keep OE# and/or RD# low even if RXF# goes high.

Comment: This did the trick. My mistake was in not registering the ft data input. Registering the data input on the positive FT clock edge when RXF# and RD# low and then using that works, as you've indicated.